# Am I pruning my pepper plants optimally?

Tags: vegetables, pruning, peppers, technique, overwintering

I usually prune my pepper plants at the start of winter, just above the second set of nodes. I have been doing this for about eight years now and I'm interested to see if there is a better or more correct way that it should be done.

Once the first few weeks of winter set in, I chop the plants just above the first set of leaves (the topmost set). I then remove each set of limbs all the way back to the second set of nodes from top to bottom, making sure to leave the nodes themselves so that they regrow the next year.

Comment: Don't forget that you can root the cuttings you prune off and get more plants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a great pruning system, and as you've been sucessfully using it for 8 years, I don't see why you should switch methods, unless you want to. There isn't really a 'best' way.